# Existence of solution(s) to a the quadratic matrix equation $P^T Q P - A^T P - P^T A + R = 0$?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, fundamental-solution

While investing an optimization problem, I ended up with the following quadratic matrix equation
$$ P^T Q P - A^T P - P^T A + R = 0$$
in which $Q, A$ and $R$ are $n\times n$ real matrices and $Q$ and $R$ are symmetric positive. $P$ is the unknown matrix to be determined.

Of course, if we consider $P = P^T$, we recover the standard Ricatti equation for which conditions for the existence and potential unicity of symmetric solutions are well-known to me.
Unfortunately, I do not manage to find any reference on the above "non-symmetric" equivalent.

Is any of you aware of references or results on the existence of solutions to this equation?

Thanks in advance for your help !